# VS tool to find candidates for expressions

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Are there any tools that augment/replace intellisense with a search of for expressions that will result in a given type?

I'm thinking of the case where I need to get some particular object and I known the type and will recognize the name but don't know what sequence of objects to jump thought to get to it. Such a tool would do a breadth first search of all options and list anything that has the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, I know, but I'm giving it a shot in case you didn't find anything. Intellisense has the Resolve option (from at least Visual Studio 2005), with which you type your particular object straight, and then with right-clicking you can choose Resolve, which will add the library required to the list at the top of your class.

Similarly, [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) might have something fancier for you.